# How does CQRS help reduce lock contention, when receivers still need to update their read store?

Tags: .net, sql-server, cqrs

One of the reasons i'm looking at CQRS is reduce lock contention on my database, so that the **writes** simply update the normalized structure, and the **reads** can lookup the data it needs, free from competing writes.

Assuming the following setup:

1. Write system writing to it's own normalized DB (`WriteDb`)
2. Write system publishing message onto bus to raise event
3. Read system picking up message, updating it's materialized view (seperate `ReadDb`)
4. Read system reading from materialized view (`ReadDb`)

Won't there still be lock contention during step 3 & 4? The read system still needs to update it's copy of the data, which may happen at the same time as the reads, so i just see this as *reducing* lock contention, due to narrow/less indexes.. but the danger is still there, albeit to a lesser extent.

What are some strategies to help mitigate this issue? (**is** this an issue, or am i overthinking it?). Is Event Sourcing the only way?

Note: i'm on .NET / SQL .. so bonus points for any answers specific to that stack :)

Thanks

Comment: if you dont want readers blocked by writers use snapshot isolation.

Comment: @MartinSmith why not RCSI? It should be noticeably cheaper, resource-wise.

Comment: @RogerWolf  Is RCSI a term you invented? :)

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu - It is "Read Committed Snapshot Isolation" - which is lighter weight than full snapshot isolation - my comment above was referring to the snapshot isolation concept in general - not intended to be a specific recommendation for SI over RCSI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Won't there still be lock contention during step 3 & 4

A lock is involved, even if only at row/document level, but the idea is that writes are happening a lot less frequent than reads so a lock between Write&Read is (sufficient) rare.

> but the danger is still there, albeit to a lesser extent

What danger? If you mean that is affecting reading speed then yes, however it is a lot less painful than a multi-table/multi-join lock.

Using CQRS you can (and should) create read-models (tables if you are using SQL) that are self sufficient for a query, i.e. you won't need any join; in this way the query will be faster and the probability of a locked read will be lower.

> Is Event Sourcing the only way?

Event sourcing doesn't need to use transactions so a lock is even smaller (faster) than in plain CQRS - that is the reason why ES is faster on the read side.

One other solution is to use an Event log (not an Event store) that is used only as the source of events for the read-models update. One inconvenient is that this is another moving part of your architecture and it also must be kept in sync with the events from the write-models in an asynchronous way (using a thread or something).

Articles about using an Event log:

- [Event log vs event streams](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dddcqrs/uOoSr_uYpSY)
- [Event Sourcing - Projections (go to Rebuilding)](https://abdullin.com/post/event-sourcing-projections/)

Comment: Good answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CQRS fundamentally reduces overall lock contention (not to mention eliminating it). As you have pointed out, the read model still needs to be updated. If you look from the outside, the read/write ratio does not depend on whether the system is implemented using CQRS or not. (The actual lock contention behavior would heavily depend on system implementation.)

One may argue that CQRS can reduce lock contention on the write side, but to me, this by itself does not justify the added overall system complexity.

In my understanding, the benefits of CQRS are 1) to allow flexible read models for better read performance, and more importantly 2) a "stepping stone" towards Event Sourcing (as Greg Young stated in [his DDD Europe 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=7m32s)).

Thus, I don't think "reduced" lock contention would be a factor in deciding whether to choose CQRS.

As to Event Sourcing, again, it is not meant to be a technical help to CQRS, but more of an architectural motivation of doing it.